# Do demo models receive updates?

Tags: update

I was given a Lumia 610 by Nokia for development purposes. The demo models seem to run a custom ROM and after hard resetting the device the demo content is reinstalled.

Will this device receive system updates via the internet, or will I have to take it into Nokia?

Comment: What is the full version of it? Is it 7.10.8779?

Comment: OS Version: 7.10.8773.98 and the model on the box appears to be CV MY DEMO

Comment: 8773 is Tango. So you have a very updated device. But I don't know if there are Lumia 610 devices with less than 8773.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on many factors, most of which are out of your control.  I've had a number of developer devices over the past two years.  Most of them are stuck with old versions and not updateable at this time.

In some cases I was able to download the update files and force the update.  But other times, e.g. the Mango update, I couldn't make it work on the older phones.

Best advice, talk to a Nokia evangelist and see what they say.

Comment: In this case I was able to flash a retail ROM. I have just received the latest update notification.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one to answer. As of now I don't think there have been any updates for the 610 to compare against, but There were some cases where demo/developer models **did not** receive updates. The reason given was that the demo phone was actually different.

We really can't know for certain until they either announce it or you see one come down, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on how much of a development version it is -- however, I understand that the Nokia Lumias being made available to developers are from retail stock, and still need unlocking by the developer they're given to, so I would expect them to be eligible for upgrades in the normal manner.

Comment: Some are retail, but mine doesn't seem to be. The demo models still need to be unlocked as well.

Comment: I know some of the early devices were pre-unlocked (which led to "issues" when it came around to the annual renewal of the unlock)